# ListView section headers don't seem to be working on Android, but they work fine on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

Has anyone had success with ListView section headers on Android? Using the documentation and a few handy tutorials I was able to build this for iOS:

[image: ListView Section Header Example]

When we run the code on Android (Lollipop and Marshmallow) the ListView just acts like a ScrollView...no section headers :(

Has anyone else run into issues with the ListView on Android? Were you able solve them? We're no against building a separate component for Android so if you know of another react-native component that can be used to achieve this effect that would be great too.

Comment: That's currently an iOS only feature. Here's the feature request for it: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/scrollview-sticky-section-headers-on-android/ , so it might be supported in a later version.

Comment: Thanks @lyle. I'll keep an eye on the PR